# how to fill image in view with some percentage of color in android

Tags: android

How to fill the image according to percentage of `TextView`. and it should change according to percentage of `TextView` .

**CODE:**

```
 private void displayData(String data) {
    if (data != null) { 
        battery.setText(data);
  int x=Integer.parseInt(battery.getText().toString());
  image_level.setMaxHeight(x);
    }
 }
```

This is my `TextView` i am getting data as 100 or some 60 like that.what ever value i got that much level my `ImageView` should fill with color and display.

```
<TextView  android:id="@+id/batterylevel"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="150dp"
 android:text="BRV Battery" 
 android:layout_below="@+id/sos"/>

<ImageView 
 android:id="@+id/image_level"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="100dp"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/batterylevel"
 android:layout_below="@+id/sos"
 android:layout_above="@+id/portbearmode"
 android:alpha="1"
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
 android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
```

in the layout i did like this i should apply any animations or simply setting any options please tell me.
if battery `TextView` is 60 it should fill blue color upto 60 and remaining 40 as white color.

Comment: I have a similar scenario, did you get any solution ?

Comment: hey have you got solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`ProgressBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html). If the component doesn't fill your requirements, then you will have to go for a custom view, in which you can use a [`ClipDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip).

Comment: hi it should be like filling battery level.i am new to this the above is my code.please send me code.how can i fill level like what ever data(value) i got in textview that much it should fill color(blue) of  image in imageview.

Comment: Sending code would assume I got some, and that's not the case. You got some ideas of the track to follow. Coding is not copy-pasting, do some research and find out a decent way to solve *your* problem.

Comment: ok snicolas,i did as  <ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/image_level"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/batterylevel"
   android:background="#AABBCC"
   
    android:layout_weight="1" 
     android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" but color of image is not filling and background is not changing

Answer (score 1):

You can set color using following ways,

```
text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

holder.text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(200,0,0));

holder.text.setTextColor(Color.argb(0,200,0,0));

<color name="errorColor">#f00</color>
```

Comment: hi not textcolor,i want to fill some percentage which i got in textview(value) to image in imageview.simply like battery level.